# Creating a line slider on a graph in android

Tags: android, graph, slider, mpandroidchart

I have created a graph with a series of data. Now I'm trying to add a slider / line marker to the chart like the one below.

I created the graph/charts using the MPAndroidChart library provided here https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart.

The graph seems to be working fine and good but i need a line slider like below so that when i touch on the graph the line slides and provides the values of the line intersecting the graph. 
Could anyone help me figure out this problem or do i have to use a different library to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: how did you achieve this circle thing on line intersection?

Comment: Yeah, for the dot i just used the MarkerView class provided in the library itself.  I created a new ChartMarker class and extended MarkerView class. Then in the constructor i passed the layout containing an image view with the dot as the src to the super. Finally set the ChartMarker instance to the chart through chart.setMarkerView(new ChartMarker(getActivity())).

Comment: Thanks Yogesh!! You can answer the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100511/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-on-highlight-point-in-line-chart so that others could benefit from it. I'll try and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature just became available: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/commits/master

However, it is not available as a release yet, so you cannot get it via gradle or maven, only via cloning the repository.

It will be in the next release v2.1.0 which will be available within the next week.

Comment: WOW! luking forward to ur new library.

Comment: That's just what i wanted. But just to get to another level, lets say we have two graphs in a single layout and both the graphs are related. Say one is for elevation and another for speed. Can we create the line sliders in such a way that when the user clicks on a entry in one graph, the corresponding entry in the second graph automatically gets highlighted. I tried modifying some codes at the onValueSelected() function but couldnt get it working. Would really appreatiate if you could suggest some possible ways. Thanks.

Comment: In onValueSelected(...) call highlightValues(Highlight[] highs) on the other chart with the Highlight object provided by the onValueSelected method.

Comment: Thank you!!! that worked perfectly. I was using hightlightValue() instead earlier, and was also passing incorrect parameters to it. But changing the function worked just perfectly. :) ... Looking forward to using your new library. You have got yourself an achievement right there.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you elaborate a little more on the solution? I have been searching for days to get a line slider implemented in my chart. Does this solution include an explicit line slider(like a seekbar) or is it just the HighlightLine ?

Comment: It is actualy just a highlight line. From library version 2.1.0 we have a method mChart.setHighlightIndicatorEnabled(true) that will display the highlight line for the chart. And if you want to make two charts to be in sync then setOnChartValueSelectedListener() to the chart1. Then on the overridden onValueSelected(...,Highlight highlight) call chart2.highlightValues(new Highlight[]{highlight}). This will make the two charts highlight lines in sync