# How can I draw a circle on highlight point in line chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using mpchart to draw my charts.I wanted to increase the circle size of intersection point of highlighter and line dataset. How can I achieve this?[image]

I read somewhere that we can add another dataset with highlighted point and increase its circle size. Is that really a good approach if my highlighter will be dragged back and forth and I'll have to update the new dataset very frequently?

Comment: hello. how to draw a half line circel chart instead of line chart ( like your above line in your image)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using the MpChart Library, the library contains a MarkerView class that helps us to insert the markers for displaying the selected value in the chart. We can use this MarkerView class to display any kind of view for the selected chart data.

So for the dot I created a new **ChartMarker** class and extended **MarkerView** class. Then in the constructor I passed the layout containing an image view with the dot as the src to the super.

```
public ChartMarker(Context context) {
    //the super will take care of displaying the layout
    super(context, R.layout.layout_dot);
}
```

Finally set the ChartMarker instance to the chart through chart.setMarkerView()

```
ChartMarker elevationMarker = new ChartMarker(getActivity());
elevationChart.setMarkerView(elevationMarker);
```

And for the layout_dot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/dot"
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh!! Worked perfectly. I had to set set getXOffset to -(getWidth() / 2) and getYOffset to -(getHeight() / 2); in overridden methods to center the dot.

Comment: Yeah! you have to give some offset values to fix the centering of the dot. Glad to help

Comment: @Yogesh and Heisenberg you guys are my heroes :)

Comment: I want to do this and want to add another custom marker which shows the selected values, how can I do that?

Comment: it's bad solution because height can be different of marker towards the point (if there is no enough space to show the marker above or below the point on the chart)

Answer (score 0):

I find ultimate solution.another question only can draw one point of one dataset in linechart,if I have two dataset like below,it will not draw two point。
[image]

Below code is my solution:
(it should edit the library source code,so pls import as module)

1、in `LineChartRenderer` class

```java
    private final Paint mHighlightPointStokePaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mHighlightPointInnerPaint = new Paint();

 @Override
    public void drawHighlighted(Canvas c, Highlight[] indices) {

        LineData lineData = mChart.getLineData();
        int entryIndex = -1;

        for (Highlight high : indices) {

            ILineDataSet set = lineData.getDataSetByIndex(high.getDataSetIndex());

            if (set == null || !set.isHighlightEnabled())
                continue;

            Entry e = set.getEntryForXValue(high.getX(), high.getY());

            if (!isInBoundsX(e, set))
                continue;

            entryIndex = set.getEntryIndex(e);
            MPPointD pix = mChart.getTransformer(set.getAxisDependency()).getPixelForValues(e.getX(), e.getY() * mAnimator
                    .getPhaseY());

            high.setDraw((float) pix.x, (float) pix.y);

            // draw the lines
            drawHighlightLines(c, (float) pix.x, (float) pix.y, set);
        }

        if (entryIndex < 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (mChart instanceof BarLineChartBase) {
            BarLineChartBase chart = (BarLineChartBase) this.mChart;
            if (chart.isDrawHighlightPoint()) {
                mHighlightPointInnerPaint.reset();
                mHighlightPointInnerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mHighlightPointInnerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

                //交点外圈白环
                mHighlightPointStokePaint.reset();
                mHighlightPointStokePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mHighlightPointStokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                mHighlightPointStokePaint.setStrokeWidth(chart.getHighLightPointStrokeWidth());
                mHighlightPointStokePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                List<ILineDataSet> dataSets = lineData.getDataSets();
                for (ILineDataSet set : dataSets) {
                    if (entryIndex < set.getEntryCount()) {
                        Entry e = set.getEntryForIndex(entryIndex);
                        MPPointD pix = mChart.getTransformer(set.getAxisDependency())
                                .getPixelForValues(e.getX(), e.getY() * mAnimator.getPhaseY());

                        drawHighlightPoint(c, (float) pix.x, (float) pix.y, chart, set);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawHighlightPoint(Canvas c, float x, float y, BarLineChartBase chart, ILineDataSet set) {
        //点内圆的颜色和图表线条一致，且将颜色的不透明度调满！
        mHighlightPointInnerPaint.setColor(((255) << 24) | set.getColor());
        //绘制内圆
        c.drawCircle(x, y, chart.getHighLightPointInnerRadius(), mHighlightPointInnerPaint);
        //绘制外圆
        c.drawCircle(x, y, chart.getHighLightPointInnerRadius(), mHighlightPointStokePaint);
    }
```

2、in `BarLineChartBase` class

```java
    /**
     * flag that indicates if draw highlight point is enabled or not
     */
    protected boolean isDrawHighlightPoint = false;

    /**
     * the highlight point inner radius (px)
     */
    protected int mHighLightPointInnerRadius = 1;

    /**
     * the highlight point stroke width (px)
     */
    protected int mHighLightPointStrokeWidth = 1;

public boolean isDrawHighlightPoint() {
        return isDrawHighlightPoint;
    }

    public void setDrawHighlightPoint(boolean drawHighlightPoint) {
        isDrawHighlightPoint = drawHighlightPoint;
    }

    public int getHighLightPointInnerRadius() {
        return mHighLightPointInnerRadius;
    }

    public void setHighLightPointInnerRadius(int mHighLightPointStrokeWidth) {
        this.mHighLightPointInnerRadius = mHighLightPointStrokeWidth;
    }

    public int getHighLightPointStrokeWidth() {
        return mHighLightPointStrokeWidth;
    }

    public void setHighLightPointStrokeWidth(int mHighLightPointStrokeWidth) {
        this.mHighLightPointStrokeWidth = mHighLightPointStrokeWidth;
    }
```

3、apply to your chart

```java
        lineChart.setDrawHighlightPoint(true);
        lineChart.setHighLightPointInnerRadius(Utils.dp2px(5, context));
        lineChart.setHighLightPointStrokeWidth(Utils.dp2px(3, context));
```

Comment: I have to show exact what like your image can i get the full code refernece

Comment: how this dashed highlight line and that dialog with highlighted points is created