# MPAndroid Line Chart single data point with curve

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I want linechart as follows. I want to show only specified point (blue circled should be there) (red circled should not be there).

[image]

Comment: which point do you want to show? the max point only on your graph?

Comment: I just want to show the point which is circled in blue color. Basically I have 3 points here, (1,1) (5,5) (10,1) . all 3 data is important for me, but i want the yellow point only at (5,5)

Answer (score 1):

I think of 2 methods.

First:
disable all points and values with

```
lineDataSet.setDrawValues(dataSet.drawValues);
lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(dataSet.drawValues);
```

Then add another `LineDataSet` to the `LineChart` only containing that one point for the Maximum.
This solution causes an additional entry in the Legend.

The other solution would be a custom `MarkerView` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100511/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-on-highlight-point-in-line-chart)

Comment: Thank You! I will try and let you know. :D

Answer (score 0):

To do that first of all set your point colors to transparent as:

```
dataset.setCircleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
dataset.setCircleColorHole(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Then after that Highlight specific point as:

```
Highlight highlight = new Highlight(50f, 0); 
chart.highlightValue(highlight, false);
```

Insert your point instead of (50f,0). Never tried just think that we may do this in that way.Try this and do let me know if it works buddy :)

Comment: Okay Bro, I will check and let you know bro :D